# Unable to update parent XState machine context from child component

Tags: javascript, state-management, xstate, xstate-react

I'm building a website builder application using React and XState. I have a parent component (**`SkinsController`**) that uses a state machine (**`bookmarkMachine`**) to manage the state of bookmarks. I also have a child component (**`Editor`**) that has its own state machine (**`editorMachine`**) and is used to edit the properties of a bookmark.

When a user saves their changes in the **`Editor`**, I want to send an event to the **`bookmarkMachine`** to create a new bookmark with the updated properties. However, I'm having trouble updating the **`bookmarkMachine`** context from the **`Editor`** component.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import { assign, createMachine } from "xstate";

export const bookmarkMachine = createMachine({
  id: "bookmark",
  initial: "idle",
  context: {
    bookmarks: [],
  },
  states: {
    idle: {
      on: {
        CREATE_BOOKMARK: {
          actions: assign((context, event) => {
            const newBookmark = {
              id: event.id,
              inputValue: event.inputValue,
              hState: event.hState,
              satState: event.satState,
              liState: event.liState,
              imageURL: event.imageURL,
            };
            context.bookmarks.push(newBookmark);
          }),
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Editor from "./Editor";
import { useMachine } from "@xstate/react";
import { bookmarkMachine } from "../machines/bookmarkMachine";

export default function SkiController() {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState(null);
  const [state, send] = useMachine(bookmarkMachine);
  const handleClick = (componentNumber) => {
    setComponent(componentNumber);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sController">
      <div className="leftContainer">
        {component === 1 && <Editor sendBookmarks={send} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

import React from "react";
import { useMachine } from "@xstate/react";
import Rename from "./Rename";
import { editorMachine } from "../machines/editorMachine";

const Editor = ({ sendBookmarks }) => {
  const [state, send] = useMachine(editorMachine);
  const handleOpenRename = () => send("OPEN_RENAME");
  const handleCloseRename = () => send("CLOSE_RENAME");

  const handleSaveName = async (newName) => {
    send({ type: "SAVE_NAME", value: newName });

    sendBookmarks({
      type: "CREATE_BOOKMARK",
      id: newName,
      inputValue: newName,
      hState: state.context.hState,
      satState: state.context.satState,
      liState: state.context.liState,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="Editor draggable">
      <button onClick={handleOpenRename}>Rename</button>
      <Rename
        isOpen={state.matches("renaming")}
        onClose={handleCloseRename}
        onSave={handleSaveName}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

When I try to save the changes in the **`Editor`**, I expect the **`bookmarkMachine`** context to be updated with the new bookmark. However, the context is not being updated and I'm not seeing any errors.

How can I update the **`bookmarkMachine`** context from the **`Editor`** component?

When a user saves their changes in the **`Editor`**, I want to send an event to the **`bookmarkMachine`** to create a new bookmark with the updated properties. However, I'm having trouble updating the **`bookmarkMachine`** context from the **`Editor`** component.

When I try to save the changes in the **`Editor`**, I expect the **`bookmarkMachine`** context to be updated with the new bookmark. However, the context is not being updated and I'm not seeing any errors.

How can I update the **`bookmarkMachine`** context from the **`Editor`** component?

Comment: What I can see as a possible issue is that in your action assigner, you should return the newly created context, instead of mutating the existing one.